# How can I reduce my Docker Image size for deployment?

Tags: node.js, docker

So I've just created a very basic Node app. I want to practice putting it into a docker container and deploying it on another server

I'm using the steps here (https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) to create a dockerfile that builds a docker image.

I want to take this image and copy it to the server.

So I'm running this command to save it to a tar file which I would copy to the server.

```
docker save -o <save image to path> <image name>
```

Upon running that command, my image is 750Mbs in size - this is for a hello world node application.

So I kind of get why this is the case - that 750Mb is for all the layers described in the dockerfile, include node:8 which basically contains the OS to run Node in.

My question is, 750mb is a very big file every time I want to do a deployment. Is it possible to tell docker when running the SAVE command not to package up all the layers? Preferably, it should only package up my custom files for my application plus the dockerfile and it would build the image on the server.

EDIT - my docker file

```
FROM node:8

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production


# Bundle app source
COPY . .

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

Comment: base from the alpine image,

Comment: There are various things you can do in the Dockerfile that are more or less efficient.  If you’re installing a full C toolchain and all of your dev dependencies, your image will just be huge.  Sharing the Dockerfile would be helpful.

Comment: @DavidMaze - Hi, I've editted the question description to contain my dockerfile

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I took one of my current projects and basically ran your Dockerfile...and got a 1.1 GB `docker save` tar file.  It compresses well, but a 345 MB gzipped tar file still isn't what you're after.  "Use an Alpine base image" is somewhat helpful, but not a silver bullet; switching it to be `FROM node:8-alpine` reduces it to a 514 MB uncompressed tar file.

If you don't already have a `.dockerignore` file, then your entire existing `node_modules` directory will get copied into the image.  (In particular, the `COPY . .` step will copy your entire working tree in, overwriting the installed modules from the previous step.)  It can just contain the single line

```
node_modules
```

The Alpine base image, plus not emitting a duplicate `node_modules` tree, gets me down to 382 MB uncompressed.

Notice in your example that your `npm install` step includes all of the development dependencies as well as the runtime dependencies.  That can be a significant cost.  If your application doesn't need any precompilation (it is plain JavaScript that Node can run directly) then you can add that `--only=production` flag and it will help.

If you do need some level of precompilation (Babel, Webpack, Typescript, ...) then you need a multi-stage build.  My actual Dockerfile has three stages.  The first does the compilation, and produces a `dist` directory with runnable JavaScript.  The second produces the `node_modules` tree I need at runtime.  The third (since we're counting bytes here) copies only the parts we really need from the first two stages.

The sum looks like:

```sh
FROM node:8-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Installing dependencies first can save time on rebuilds
# We do need the full (dev) dependencies here
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
# Then copy in the actual sources we need and build
COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY src/ ./src/
RUN yarn build

FROM node:8-alpine AS deps
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# This _only_ builds a runtime node_modules tree.
# We won't need the package.json to actually run the application.
# If you needed developer-oriented tools to do this install they'd
# be isolated to this stage.
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --production

FROM node:8-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=deps /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules/
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist/
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]
```

`docker save` on this produces a 108 MB uncompressed tar file.

One thing you will notice, if you `docker save node:8-alpine`, is that that image is 71 MB on its own.  When you `docker save` you are forced to copy that every time, and when you `docker load` it you will get a distinct copy of it every time.  The only way around this is to have a registry server of some sort (Docker Hub, a cloud-hosted thing like Google GCR or AWS ECR, something you run yourself) and `docker push` and `docker pull` from there.

It turns out the `node:8` image is *huge*; half its size is a full C toolchain (that single layer is 320 MB alone) (try running `docker history node:8`).  The [standard node image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) also has a `node:8-slim` variant which is still Debian-based (and so larger than the Alpine image) but much tidier.  I get a 221 MB `docker save` tar file adapting my Dockerfile to be based on this image.  (And again if you `docker pull` it you'll get the base Node runtime once, but if you `docker load` it you'll get that over and over again.)

Answer (score 0):

- You can use a registry to pull the images, it should only download the diff :

> Docker includes git-like capabilities for tracking successive versions of a container, inspecting the diff between versions, committing new versions, rolling back etc. The history also includes how a container was assembled and by whom, so you get full traceability from the production server all the way back to the upstream developer. Docker also implements incremental uploads and downloads, similar to git pull, so new versions of a container can be transferred by only sending diffs.
>   [source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/faq/#what-does-docker-technology-add-to-just-plain-lxc)

- Or you can build your image on the production server, it will reuse the `node:8` image and you only need to deploy your code.

This solution has limitations as it can take a lot of time to build especially if it is running on a small server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own Docker based register service using the `registry:2` image. Host it somewhere you want the image being authenticated and updated and pull them as you want them to be.