# Is there any way to optimize size of Docker Image?

Tags: angular, docker, optimization, docker-image

I have Angular application running locally with V10. I am trying to build an Docker image with help of Dockerfile.But while building images, my Docker image size is building huge as 1.32GB. Is there any way to reduce its size ?

Below is the Dockerfile which i wrote

```
# base image
FROM node:12.2.0

# set working directory (also creates two folders needed for cypress)
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app && mkdir /usr/src/app/cypress && mkdir /usr/src/app/cypress/plugins
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app and cache app dependencies
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install --silent
EXPOSE 4200
# start app 
CMD ["npm", "run", "ng serve"]
```

Please Note:- Locally the root folder is showing the property as  1,14,774 items, totaling 1.3 GB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reduce my Docker Image size for deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52259563/how-can-i-reduce-my-docker-image-size-for-deployment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue, by not copying node_modules folder while creating images. So what i did is i just took clone from github where node_modules folder itself is not available and create the image. After that total size becomes only 14.48 MB. So, removing node_modules resolve my issue.

Comment: awesome, I did this and It worked nice, the size of docker image has reduced a lot after this, see below the code: 
WORKDIR /app
ADD build /app/build
ADD dist /app/dist

Answer (score 0):

Your [base image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/node/library/node/12.2.0/images/sha256-cbd7790d01e6ff95deefd60dcf3d5baf4c65f2584142123cbf5b060fa3d2dd74?context=explore) uncompressed size is 906MB. I would advice you to try with the [slim version](https://hub.docker.com/layers/node/library/node/12.2.0-slim/images/sha256-f2c697c33ba3223347dfbe2a6cfdd9081405e3535c73f84cfc912fb9d7202e10?context=explore) which is 150MB.

```
# base image
FROM node:12.2.0-slim

# set working directory (also creates two folders needed for cypress)
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app && mkdir /usr/src/app/cypress && mkdir /usr/src/app/cypress/plugins
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app and cache app dependencies
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install --silent
EXPOSE 4200
# start app 
CMD ["npm", "run", "ng serve"]
```

There is also the [alpine version](https://hub.docker.com/layers/node/library/node/12.2.0-alpine/images/sha256-f391dabf9dce53bfc184823f18b7703db8dfead7f25e5b376865e690433bec78?context=explore) which is even smaller (77.7MB).