# Angular docker file takes too much time to build

Tags: angular, docker

I am using dockerfile to build and run. Docker file build takes 10-15 minutes to build. But    `npm run build` takes 2-3 minutes. Any ideas how I can improve this docker file for faster build time.

```sh
FROM node:14.18-alpine as build
WORKDIR /usr/local/frontend
RUN npm cache clean --force
COPY ./ /usr/local/frontend/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

# Nginx
FROM nginx:1.21-alpine
# COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/local/frontend/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
# CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
EXPOSE 9020
```

Comment: How big is the docker image generated? Probably is related to improvement of app performance, probably you have many functions and methods repeated all over your code. That's why it takes so much to load, it's double work for compiler. Try to analize you code and don't repeat code.

Comment: Size is 1.793GB

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66240418/is-there-any-way-to-optimize-size-of-docker-image

Comment: The Dockerfile looks fine; I'd make a couple of minor tweaks but none of those would have a large-scale effect on performance like what you're describing.  If the build context is in the gigabyte range then the internal mechanics of `docker build` will be slow but you'll see that at the very beginning, not on the `RUN npm run build` step.

Comment: I guess RUN npm install may take time, because it has to download all the npm libraries mentioned in the package.json file

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the package.json file first and then do `npm install`, you create a cache layer with all the npm packages that only needs to be refreshed if you change the package.json file.

I don't think the `cache clean` does anything since the image is a 'blank' node  image at the point where you run it.

```
FROM node:14.18-alpine as build
WORKDIR /usr/local/frontend
RUN npm cache clean --force
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /usr/local/frontend/
RUN npm run build --prod

# Nginx
FROM nginx:1.21-alpine
# COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/local/frontend/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
# CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
EXPOSE 9020
```